# When to use $scope.$watch in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am aware $scope.$watch should be used in directives. However, I believe I have a special case where $scope.$watch may be necessary in the controller. I have a date variable on the controller in this format:

```
$scope.myDateParts = {year: 2014, month: 1, day: 1};
```

I need another varible that represents a date of `myDateParts`. So, if the variable above changes the date needs to change as well:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date($scope.myDateParts.year, $scope.myDateParts.month, $scope.myDateParts.day);
```

myDateParts and myDate need to stay in sync. My original solution was to manually change myDate when myDateParts change. But, there are many places where `myDateParts` can change and it is difficult to keep track of every place it changes. To solve this I wanted to use $scope.$watch on myDateParts. I am not sure if this is the right approach to solve this problem. My question is - is using $scope.$watch in this manner the right way to do this? If not can you suggest a technique suitable for this situation?

Comment: Can't you just use a method instead of a property? ie having `$scope.myDate = funtion(){return new Date (...) }` ?

As long as you don't update `$scope.myDateParts` "outside" the scope, myDate() will be called again an return the new result.

Comment: If I have the method binded to an ng-show it will be called before any of its local ($scope) variables are initialized. I can always check if the local variables have a value but I don't think it will pass code review because if the local variables have not been initialized I have to return NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it may be a good use for it. Since `new Date()` will only construct an object one time, it will not update automatically when you update `$scope.myDateParts`, which you have already mentioned.

You'd do something like:

```
$scope.$watch('myDateParts', function() {
    // create new date 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use watch on myDateParts , no problem using watch in controller, but it affects performance of the app, for one watch no such performance problem.

Comment: I wouldn't use $watch in a controller, it makes the controller hard to unit test. That's a much bigger problem than performance.